# Error when using match, expected struct string, but found &str when using match

Tags: rust

I'm getting the below error when using `match`.

> "add" => {    |         ^^^^^ expected struct `String`, found `&str`
>
> match input_string {    |           ------------ this expression has
> type `String` 22 |         "add" => {    |         ^^^^^ expected
> struct `String`, found `&str`

I'm not exactly sure how to resolve this.

Ideally, rust will prompt user to enter either add, subtract, etc.

It should be followed by the match statement.

```
use std::io;

fn add(x1: i32, x2: i32) -> i32 {
    return x1 + x2;
}
fn subtract(x1: i32, x2: i32) -> i32 {
    return x1 - x2;
}
fn multiply(x1: i32, x2: i32) -> i32 {
    return x1 * x2;
}
fn divide(x1: i32, x2: i32) -> i32 {
    return x1 / x2;
}

fn main() {
    let mut input_string = String::new();
    println!("Enter either add, substract, multiply, or divide:");
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input_string).unwrap();

    match input_string {
        "add" => {
            let mut input_number = String::new();

            io::stdin()
                .read_line(&mut input_number)
                .expect("Not a valid string");

            println!("Number 1 {}", input_number);
            let mut input_number2 = String::new();
            io::stdin()
                .read_line(&mut input_number2)
                .expect("Not a valid string");

            println!("Number 2 {}", input_number2);

            let parsedNumb1: i32 = input_number.trim().parse().unwrap();
            let parsedNumb2: i32 = input_number2.trim().parse().unwrap();
            add(parsedNumb1, parsedNumb2);
        }
    }
}
```

Rust playground

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c9387928038a5b21559cb1791a731184

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string literal like `"add"` has type `&str`, which can't be directly matched against a value of type `String`. You can use [`.as_str()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_str) to get a string slice from the `String`. To get the word to match exactly, you will also need to remove the newline in `input_string`, which can be done with [`.trim_end()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.trim_end).

```
match input_string.as_str().trim_end() {
```

Alternatively, it is sufficient to just match on the result of `trim_end()` as it returns a string slice:

```
match input_string.trim_end() {
```

After these modifications, you need to add a catchall case so that the `match` is exhaustive, e.g.

```
c => println!("Invalid command: {c}")
```

Comment: I get ```the matched value is of type `&str`
help: ensure that all possible cases are being handled by adding a match arm with a wildcard pattern or an explicit pattern as shown```

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0b78baf1631c0546b667b8a99f304904

Comment: @BARNOWL As stated at the end of my answer, you need to add a catchall case like `c => println!("Invalid command: {c}")`. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=81fc7cbe67eb5481858aefc3e98b0d80)

Answer (score 2):

Borrow the `String` as a `&str` using [`String::as_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_str)

```
match input_string.as_str() {
  "add" => {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

You can get the same result with the old borrow-unborrow trick to trigger a deref, but most people (myself included) find that unreadable and confusing.

```
match &*input_string {
  "add" => {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, you've matched `"add"`, but there are lots of strings that aren't equal to that. You need to add a catch-all to your match, because it's impossible to truly match *every* string exhaustively. Rust is rightly warning you that there are strings which don't match any of your match arms.

Comment: got it thanks, ill take a look into some more, but this answer gets me through :)